# Applying a conditional to a DateTime

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, sensors

I have sensor readings that I need to check for malfunctions. Any reading below 550 should be flagged up, the datetime records each 8 sensor every second.

If at any given point it goes below 550 for more than 10 minutes it should print the filename (which is also in the column).

```
for dataframe in df:
        if((df["sensor_1"] < 550).all() & df["DateTime"] <longer than 10 minutes>):
            print(dataframe["filename"]
```

Comment: Would you be able to share a sample dataset that uses the structure you are parsing?

Comment: What is your question? What problem are you having? Please take your time to follow the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).